# Read single field of object using Aeson without writing a FromJSON instance

Tags: haskell, aeson

How do I read a single field (by name) from a JSON object using Aeson, without writing any type class instance?

Comment: Could you please provide an example of what you precisely need?. As far as I know you can derive Aeson's type classes using `Generics`, so you don't need to write the instance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `decode` to read a JSON `ByteString` as a `Maybe Value`, since `Value` already has a `FromJSON` instance:

```
*Q54233506 Q54233506> :set -XOverloadedStrings
*Q54233506 Q54233506> decode "{ \"foo\": \"bar\", \"baz\": 42 }" :: Maybe Value
Just (Object (fromList [("foo",String "bar"),("baz",Number 42.0)]))
```

From there, you can use one of the techniques described in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53969550/126014) to extract data from the `Value`.

For example, you can use the lenses from [lens-aeson](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-aeson) to extract the `foo` and `baz` values:

```
*Q54233506 Q54233506> :set -XOverloadedStrings
*Q54233506 Q54233506> v = decode "{ \"foo\": \"bar\", \"baz\": 42 }" :: Maybe Value
*Q54233506 Q54233506> v >>= (^? key "foo")
Just (String "bar")
*Q54233506 Q54233506> v >>= (^? key "baz")
Just (Number 42.0)
```

You can further compose this with `_String` or `_Number` to extract text or numbers:

```
*Q54233506 Q54233506> v >>= (^? key "foo") >>= (^? _String)
Just "bar"
*Q54233506 Q54233506> v >>= (^? key "baz") >>= (^? _Number)
Just 42.0
```

Comment: Works the same with [aeson-optics](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-optics).

Answer (score 0):

[aeson-combinators](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-combinators)
package contains combinators that allow decoding/encoding JSON without the need for FromJSON / ToJSON instances.

This can be very convenient in general, for example, when decoding depends on other information such as HTTP header values.

In your case, you can use `key :: Text -> Decoder a -> Decoder a` [combinator](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-combinators-0.0.5.0/docs/Data-Aeson-Combinators-Decode.html#g:9) to
get value of given key.

Check it out!